# How to test window.location.assign using react wrapper?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I have a `react` component which navigates to a different pages based on the value of **somecondition**. For example:

```
if (somecondition) {
 window.location.assign('some link')}
}
```

How would I test this **somecondition** using `enzyme` wrapper ?

Comment: Just mock the assign function and test for the call of the mock function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using enzyme and jest, your test could look like this:

```
test('should redirect', () => {
  // SETUP
  window.location.assign = jest.fn()

  // EXECUTE
  const wrapper = shallow(<Component {...props} />)
  wrapper.instance().callYourFunction()

  // VERIFY
  expect(window.location.assign).toHaveBeenCalled()
  window.location.assign.mockClear()
})
```